# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Screen Problems after Running "apt autoremove"

Tags: apt, 20.04, nvidia

For the purpose of this query, I yet again did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 from my DVD iso, specifying full install, adding proprietary material, but NOT upgrading as part of the installation (I do that later), on a recently-acquired 4TB disk.  After the installation, but before booting into the "new" system, I disabled the Internet.  After the initial boot, I removed "unattended-upgrades" (I run "apt" manually), added "users" (with appropriate permissions), removed "quiet splash" from "/etc/default/grub" and activated the change with "update-grub" (I like to see boot and shutdown messages), and shut down the computer.
After reconnecting the Internet, I rebooted, ran "apt update" and "apt dist-upgrade" to bring my system to 20.04.6, then ran "apt install lightdm" and invoked it, then ran "apt install gnome-shell-extensions" (allowing me to change to "Gnome Classic" on the GUI).
When running "apt dist-upgrade" I get the message "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:", followed by a package list, and the sentence "Use 'apt autoremove'  to remove them.".
I learned the hard way that, if I run "apt autoremove", the usable portion of the screen (command line [tty1-tty6] and GUI [tty7]) decreases both horizontally and vertically, and cursor movement becomes erratic.
To assist with this submission, I ran "apt autoremove | tee autoremove.out", and aborted the autoremove execution.  Following is the contents of "autoremove.out":

```
"Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gir1.2-goa-1.0 gstreamer1.0-vaapi
  libfwupdplugin1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libllvm11 libnvidia-cfg1-470
  libnvidia-common-470 libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-encode-470
  libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470
  libva-wayland2 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxmlb1 libxnvctrl0
  nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-kernel-source-470 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-470 screen-resolution-extra
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 25 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 507 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort."
```

Given that the video card in this computer is a "Zotac GeForce GTX650", with NVIDIA hardware, I suspect that one or more of the 25 packages which I have been invited to delete (probably of those nVidia-related) should actually be RETAINED.
Assuming that I am correct, I ask
QUESTION 1: Which of the 25 packages should I keep to avoid the video problems I experienced?   and
QUESTION 2: Is "apt-mark manual    ...", where , , et cetera is/are the answer(s) to QUESTION 1, the optimum method of keeping said packages?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^`. It will pin all these packages as dependencies so that they will not be autoremoved, and it will also reinstall all the necessary packages for Ubuntu Desktop.

Afterwards, install (if necessary, reinstall) the NVidia driver from the Additional Driver tab in `Software & Sources`.